# Configuring AD with Geoserver

Tags: active-directory, gis, geoserver

I am trying to configure AD with Geoserver as an authentication method. However am getting en error which I can see in the log. Has anyone encountered this:

`05 May 09:49:30 WARN   [geoserver.security] - Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.ParseException: Encountered "" at line 1, column 2.
Was expecting:
<SPACED_EQUALS> ...

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Failed to parse DN; nested exception is org.springframework.ldap.core.ParseException: Encountered "" at line 1, column 2.
`

Any help will be appreciated.

I have configured AD with Geoserver using the documentation however I am still getting the same error.

Comment: what have you put as the `dn`?

Comment: using version 2.22.1 of geoserver, I have entered name, server url and for user lookup pattern field just using cn, as on our AD usernameAttribute is cn. The Server URL is appended with following format OU={value here},DC={value here},DC={value here}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: Hi Ian, followed your advice and saw it complains about Bad credentials. However I am sure I am putting in the correct credentials but I still get the same error message in the log [geoserver.security] - Bad credentials

Comment: Now I am getting:

[geoserver.security] - Failed to negotiate TLS session; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target